# Sitescope regular expression

Tags: regex, sitescope

I will like to create an alert if an event has `“httpStatus” : 400` and `“errorCode” : “40000”`.

Can someone help with a regular expression? The log looks something like this:

```
“UserMessage” : “Bad Request”,
“DeveloperMessage” : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxcxxx
“HttpStatus” : 400,
“ErrorCode” : “40000”,
“GatewayErrors : “xxxx”
Xxxxxx
Xxxxxx
```

I tried string search /“HtHttpStatus” : 400, “ErrorCode” : “40000” and /[“HttpStatus” : 400], [“ErrorCode” : “40000” ]a

Comment: please edit the post to include what you have tried so far.

Comment: Just do a string search `“HttpStatus” : 400, “ErrorCode” : “40000”`

Answer (score 0):

try Regex: `/“HttpStatus” : 400,.*“ErrorCode” : “40000”/s`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/G3wYoI/1)

As mentioned in this [link](http://193.138.212.38:81/SiteScope/docs/regexp.htm#mode_modify), `/s` considers the content as being on a single line, ignoring intervening carriage returns and new line characters. With this modifier both the Consider the content as being on a single line, ignoring intervening carriage returns and new line characters. With this modifier both the [\w\W]* character class and the .* pattern will match across new lines and carriage returns. character class and the `.*` pattern will match across new lines and carriage returns.